# checking if a checkbox is selected using a variable as the checkbox name

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am looking for something like this but can't find any information anywhere..

```
Match regday = Regex.Match(oMail.HtmlBody, @"(Monday)|(Tuesday)|(Wednesday)|(Thursday)|(Friday)|(Saturday)|(Sunday)");
                              if (regday.Success)
                              {
                                  if([regday.Groups[0].Value].checked == true){
                                       Console.WriteLine("works");
                                  }
                              }
```

I have a checkbox called Monday, I could do "Monday.checked == true" for example.
When regex(regday) finds the correct day. I want it to check if the (found day).checked = true

where the regday.Group[0].Value would be the same as a checkbox name. Using c#. If it's not possible I can find a workaround.

Comment: could you please post here both your markup code and your server side code. Thanks.

Comment: Use an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if (this.Controls.Find(regday.Groups[0].Value).Checked)
```

Find control by name in collection